# How to get the file comments from NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In macOS you can write a comment for each file. For example in the Get Info.

[image]

By using the method:

```
NSDate *date = nil;
[url getResourceValue:&date forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
```

I can get the date and time of file creation as well as other additional information. But I did not find how to use this method to get a comment.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: The comments are a feature of the Finder. So you could ask the Finder.

Comment: FYI - The `mdls` command shows the comment of a file with the key of `kMDItemFinderComment`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. Your suggestion helped to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision was suggested by rmaddy.

```
NSMetadataItem *originalFileMetadata = [[NSMetadataItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file/path"]];
NSString * comment = [originalFileMetadata valueForAttribute:@"kMDItemFinderComment"];
NSLog(@"%@ ", comment);
```